# How to display all members of a given subsequence on the console?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand why I can't print only the members of a subsequence of an array, that is equal to an integer from the input. The array is also read from the console. When i run the program only the first of these members does come up, but with him also a seemingly random number of zeros, while the rest of the subsequence is omitted. If there's a better way than to use a second array, I'll be grateful if you share it. Okay, to specify- I want to know how to print all the members of the aforementioned subsequence, can you please give me a useful advice or sample? Here's the input, output and code:

4 4 56 57 58

8

4 0 0 0 0

instead of 4 4

```
    int v = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] valueHolder = new int[arr1.Length];
        int currentSum = 0;
        for (int endIndex = 0; endIndex <= arr1.Length -1; endIndex++)
        {
            currentSum = 0;
            for (int currentSumIndex = endIndex; currentSumIndex >= 0;                 currentSumIndex--)
            {
                currentSum += arr1[currentSumIndex];
                if (currentSum == v)
                {
                    valueHolder[currentSumIndex] = arr1[currentSumIndex];
                }
                if (currentSum == v)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= valueHolder.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(valueHolder[i] + " ");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: Is you question "why when I print all elements in array I see 0 for elements that where not assigned to instead of nothing"? Not sure what else you could be asking with your current code...

Comment: Yeah, but also why only 1 of the members of the subsequence is printed on the console?

Comment: I think you would be best served by putting a break point on the line of the first for loop then stepping through your code.  If you take a pad of paper and write each of the variables states as you go through it then it will be pretty obvious what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be best served by putting a break point on the line of the first for loop then stepping through your code.  If you take a pad of paper and write each of the variables states as you go through it then it will be pretty obvious what's going on.

However, just to help you out.

In the first pass of the outer loop (`endIndex = 0`), the inner loop does NOT execute. `currentSumIndex = endIndex` which equals zero, which does not pass the `currentSumIndex >= 0` test.  Therefore the first `4` is skipped.

In the second pass, the number `4` is emitted because currentSum equals 4.  However, the values of 0 are also emitted because you are walking the entire valueHolder array and spitting all of the empty values out.

From the third pass forward, currentSum will never equal the number you typed in:
The first pass of the inner loop sets `currentSum` to 56, which does not equal `v`.  The second pass of the inner loops sets it to 56+4 ( `currentSum += arr1[currentSumIndex]` ) which is 60.  Therefore, nothing will ever be emitted again as currentSum will always be the sum of all numbers from the current array position going backward to the beginning array position and therefore will always be greater than `v`

You don't need a second array.  You just need to pay attention to what your code is doing.  Side note: I have absolutely no idea why you have that inner loop or even what the `8` is supposed to represent in your example entry above.

If I was writing this, I'd change it to (assuming you can't use LINQ):

```
int v = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i= 0; i <= arr1.Length -1; i++)
{
    if (arr1[i] == v) {
        Console.Write(arr1[i].ToString() + " ");
    }
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for- your code will only find elements from the array, that are equal by themselves to v, which is part of the input (the 8 in the example I've given). That is if there are any such members. I want to show the elements, whose sum is equal to v.

Comment: @depressor: I misunderstood that part.  BTW, you shouldn't accept this as an answer if it doesn't meet your needs.